# Migrate rails application using ar-octopus gem to Rails v6.x.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1, rails-upgrade

Did Rails Dev, migration rails app using ar-octopus to rails version 6/7.

As I see there are no updates regarding the rails v6 in ar-actopus gem, did any tried to upgrade on own.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: In the absence of help from the developer, I suggest trying the Rails guide to using multiple databases and then asking about the specific sections that cause problems: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html

Comment: The readme states that "Octopus will enter into maintainance mode once Rails 6 is released - since Rails 6 will include all the features for Database Sharding / Replication into Rails Core (PR: rails/rails#34052). Once the first version of Rails 6 beta is released, there will be a migration guide to help users migrate from Octopus to Rails 6." if you look at the issues on the gem you can see that the maintainer never got around to writing the migration guide and probally isn't interested so you're really on your own figuring this one out. Thats the facts of life with open source projects.